# parse password reset email

Tags: email, parse-platform, password-recovery

I have moved our parse server onto an Elastic beanstalk instance and as a result have had to set up mailgun with the email adapter to send out password resets.

My issue now is that the links provided by the password reset email do not work:

```
Cannot GET /apps/pvrdbvgDEY6K59NQ4TmoYuoKcy0SzCfp6gCGFGE0/request_password_reset?token=SDVc5xloR4OHmInFNEKXc7Wuz&username=testuser
```

The code

```
emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)

preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false, // defaults to false

publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
appName: 'InStyle',

emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
        fromAddress: 'no-reply@domain.com',
        domain: 'domain.com',
        apiKey: 'key-EXAMPLE',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error with your code.
It works for me for current Parse-server v.2.3.2.

May be your `process.env.SERVER_URL` doesn't have `/parse` path?

In anyway, the correct path to Parse-server password recovery should be:
`/parse/apps/[appId]/request_password_reset?token=[token generated by Parse]&username=[userName]`